# remix solidity contract how to pass multiple arguments into the create button

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have a sample code look like this:

```
function HubiiCrowdsale(address _teamMultisig, uint _start, uint _end) Crowdsale(_teamMultisig, _start, _end, hubii_minimum_funding) public {
      PricingStrategy p_strategy = new FlatPricing(token_in_wei);
      CeilingStrategy c_strategy = new FixedCeiling(chunked_multiple, limit_per_address);
      FinalizeAgent f_agent = new BonusFinalizeAgent(this, bonus_base_points, _teamMultisig); 
      setPricingStrategy(p_strategy);
      setCeilingStrategy(c_strategy);
      // Testing values
      token = new CrowdsaleToken(token_name, token_symbol, token_initial_supply, token_decimals, _teamMultisig, token_mintable);
      token.setMintAgent(address(this), true);
      token.setMintAgent(address(f_agent), true);
      token.setReleaseAgent(address(f_agent));
      setFinalizeAgent(f_agent);
  }
```

it just needs me to pass (address _teamMultisig, uint _start, uint _end) three arguments into the create button to create the contract, I have tried

```
"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c" 1234 1235
```

gives error:

```
creation of browser/ballot.sol:HubiiCrowdsale errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 46
```

and:

```
{"_teamMultisig":"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c","_start":1234,"_end":1235}
```

gives error

```
creation of browser/ballot.sol:HubiiCrowdsale errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: Argument is not a number
```

what is the correct way to pass argument here?

Comment: Are you have tried (`"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", 1234, 1235`) - without parentheses - ?

Comment: i tried that, it said 'creation of browser/ballot.sol:HubiiCrowdsale errored: Send transaction failed: invalid address . if you use an injected provider, please check it is properly unlocked. '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", 1234, 1235
```

It's comma delimited

Edit: I've just seen the comment above, there's also a modifier constraint called "Crowdsale" can you please provide the code for this too as this could be causing further errors.